# PHP Cloudinary Video output not working

Tags: php, cloudinary

I uploaded a video onto cloudinary and am trying to get it to show using any of Cloudinarys PHP functions, here is the code I tried:

```
<?php
require 'cloudinary/src/Cloudinary.php';
require 'cloudinary/src/Uploader.php';
require 'cloudinary/src/Api.php';
\Cloudinary::config(array( 
  "cloud_name" => "hidden", 
  "api_key" => "hidden", 
  "api_secret" => "hidden" 
));
?>
<?php 
    echo cl_video_tag("homeCut1_h7e00z", array("video_codec"=>"auto"));
?>
```

the `hidden` was obviously replaced with the correct keys.

I tried it without the `echo` and nothing shows up, when I do it with the `echo` an image thumbnail of the video shows, but it's not playable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image that you're seeing is actually the video preview (`poster` attribute).
It looks like you're missing the `controls` parameter which cause the player controls to be displayed.

Try this instead:

```
echo cl_video_tag("homeCut1_h7e00z", array("video_codec"=>"auto", "controls"=>"controls"));
```